# Does Yosemite support the old Mail view?

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

All the screenshots I can find of Mail in Yosemite show the new Mail message view:

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Someone            | Guess what! Something happened. I don't know what is is,   |
| Something happened!| though. If I ever find out, I'll tell you.                 |
| Guess what! Some...|                                                            |
+--------------------+                                                            |
| Someone else       |                                                            |
| Guess what         |                                                            |
| Something amazin...|                                                            |
+--------------------+                                                            |
| Et cetera          |                                                            |
| You get the idea   |                                                            |
| ......             |                                                            |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Whereas I like the old view:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| From              | Subject                       | Date Recieved               |
+-------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Someone           | Something happened!           | Recently                    |
| Someone else      | Guess what                    | Less recently               |
| Et cetera         | You get the idea              | Even less recently          |
|                   |                               |                             |
|                   |                               |                             |
|                   |                               |                             |
|                   |                               |                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Guess what! Something happened. I don't know what it is, though. If I ever find |
| out, I'll tell you.                                                             |
|                                                                                 |
|                                                                                 |
|                                                                                 |
|                                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In previous versions of Mac OS, I could change to the old view. Can I do so now?

Comment: Are email grouped by conversation ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 no, they aren't in the old view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does, just open Mail.app, then open the Preferences window from the menu bar. Select the Viewing tab and then choose "Use Classic Layout". I've tested this with OS X Yosemite. Here is a screenshot:[image]